# how to get the second last value with influxDB?

Tags: grafana, monitoring, influxdb, flux

I'm configuring my Grafana for my server, and I'm trying to calculate a percentage change between the last two values of the download_bits column stocked in an InfluxDB column. My problem is as follows: I can't access the second last value, each time, I can only get the last data.

the thing that I think should work is this:

```
last_two_values = from(bucket: "speedtest")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "download_bits")
    |> last()
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: float(v: r._value) }))
    |> duplicate(column: "_value", as: "last_value")
    |> tail(n: 2)
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with first_value: r._value }))

result = last_two_values
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with diff: if r.last_value != 0.0 then (r.first_value - r.last_value) / r.last_value else 0.0 }))
    |> yield(name: "result")
```

I try to do this calculation with this data: (second_last_value - last_value) / last_value, the result with what I have is always 0

The variables are :
_value : 816246392
first_value : 816246392
last_value : 816246392
diff : 0